# Replace certain token with the content of a file (using a bash-script)

Tags: bash, sed, awk, replace

I have a file containing some text and the words `INSERT_HERE1` and `INSERT_HERE2`. I'd like to replace these words with the content of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` respectively.

I suspect `sed` or `awk` could pull it off but I've basically never used them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with Perl you can do:

```
$ cat FILE1
this is file1

$ cat FILE2
this is file2

$ cat file
foo
INSERT_HERE1
bar
INSERT_HERE2
baz

$ perl -ne 's/^INSERT_HERE(\d+)\s+$/`cat FILE$1`/e;print' file
foo
this is file1
bar
this is file2
baz
$
```

Comment: hum.. I'd like to keep dependencies down. Is perl as common to have installed as, say, sed?

Comment: @aioobe Yes. I am unaware of any modern Unix system that does not include Perl.

Comment: @aioobe Yes. Perl is ubiquitous.

Answer (score 8):

Sed does have a built-in read file command.  The commands you want would look something like this:

```
$ sed -e '/INSERT_HERE1/ {
r FILE1
d }' -e '/INSERT_HERE2/ {
r FILE2
d }' < file
```

This would output

```
foo
this is file1
bar
this is file2
baz
```

The r command reads the file, and the d command deletes the line with the `INSERT_HERE` tags.  You need to use the curly braces since sed commands and multi-line input since sed commands have to start on their own line, and depending on your shell, you may need `\` at the end of the lines to avoid premature execution.  If this is something you would use a lot, you can just put the command in a file and use `sed -f` to run it.

Comment: hm, this only seems to work with INSERT_HERE1 and INSERT_HERE2 being a single word on a single line, else the whole line of text will be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested, but would be pretty close to what you need:

```
sed -e "s/INSERT_HERE1/`cat file1.txt`/" -e "s/INSERT_HERE2/`cat file2.txt`/" <file >file.out
```

It will not properly handle a file with slashes in it, though, so you may need to tweak it a bit.

I'd recommend Perl instead, though. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $f1 = `cat file1.txt`;
my $f2 = `cat file2.txt`;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/INSERT_HERE1/$f1/;
    s/INSERT_HERE2/$f2/;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

This assumes that INSERT_HERE1 and INSERT_HERE2 may only appear once per line, and that the `file1.txt` does not include the text INSERT_HERE2 (wouldn't be difficult to fix, though). Use like this:

```
./script <file >file.out
```

Comment: Oh, sure. I'd like to go with perl but I'm going to let others use this script so I want to keep the dependencies down. I'll give your sed-line a go!

Comment: hmm.. the sed-line doesn't seem to work. Perhaps it's because `file1.txt` contains characters such as `'`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it in `sed` and allow the input file to contain any character. I don't know `awk`, unfortunately, so I can't say whether there's a better solution there. What kind of system are you on where `sed` is standard but `perl` is not?

Answer (score 1):

This is suitable for small substitution files that may be substituted many times:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        while ((getline line < ARGV[1]) > 0) {file1 = file1 nl line; nl = "\n"}; 
        close (ARGV[1]); nl = "";
        while ((getline line < ARGV[2]) > 0) {file2 = file2 nl line; nl = "\n"};
        close (ARGV[2]);
        ARGV[1] = ""; ARGV[2] = "" }
      { gsub("token1", file1); 
        gsub("token2", file2); 
        print }' file1.txt file2.txt mainfile.txt
```

You may want to add some extra newlines here and there, depending on how you want your output to look.

Comment: I would pass the file contents in as variables: `awk -v "f1=$(< file1)" -v "f2=$(< file2)" '{gsub(...`

Comment: @glenn: That's another way to do it. The way I show makes it easy to pass the filenames as arguments and allows for some pre-processing during the read, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with Bash. If you need it to be POSIX shell let me know:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=  # Needed to prevent the shell from interpreting the newlines
f1=$(< /path/to/file1.txt)
f2=$(< /path/to/file2.txt)

while read line; do 
  if [[ "$line" == "INSERT_HERE1" ]]; then
     echo "$f1"
  elif [[ "$line" == "INSERT_HERE2" ]]; then
     echo "$f2"
  else
     echo "$line"
  fi
done < /path/to/input/file
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet replaces any section that is specified in the upper array. For e.g. here

```
<!--insert.txt-->
```

with the contents of "insert.txt"

```
#!/bin/bash

replace[1]=\<!--insert.txt--\>      ; file[1]=insert.txt
replace[2]=\<!--insert2.txt--\>     ; file[2]=insert2.txt

replacelength=${#replace[@]}

cat blank.txt > tmp.txt
for i in $(seq 1 ${replacelength})
do
    echo Replacing ${file[i]} ...
    sed -e "/${replace[i]}/r ${file[i]}" -e "/${replace[i]}/d" tmp.txt > tmp_2.txt
    mv tmp_2.txt tmp.txt
done
mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

If you're not afraid of .zip files you can try this example as long as it is online: http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-04-16_contentreplace.zip

Answer (score 1):

I would use perl's in place replacement with [-i.ext](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*[_extension_]) option

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's|INSERT_HERE1|`cat FILE1`|ge; 
                 s|INSERT_HERE2|`cat FILE2`|ge;' myfile
```

Then, use `diff myfile.bak myfile` to verify: